# PHP: using $SERVER[] to return the current directory, regardless of "nice urls"

Tags: php

I am trying to return the current directory of a file in php, regardless what it says in the browser bar. I have tried:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If the url is

```
http://example.com/directory1/directory2/var1/var2/var3
```

the above code returns

```
example.com/directory1/directory2/var1/var2/var3
```

even though var1/var2/var3 are `GET_[]` variables tamed by a htaccess RewriteRule. Is there a decent way to get the directory? in the case above I would like to return:

```
example.com/directory1/directory2/
```

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about replace it with `SCRIPT_FILENAME` ?

```
str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Comment: Please check syntax. You are missing single quote after DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: ajreal: This works, after I cleaned it up. `str_replace ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));` could you update your answer?